# Python + xlrd Read large number from cell

Tags: python, xlrd

I am working on a project where i need to collect some ID's, these ID's are very large numbers and i cant find a way to store them in python without it being stored in scientific notation. One of the ID's are 373000005620158000, when i use

id = worksheet.cell_value(row, col)

print(id)

**OUTPUT:**
3.73000005620158e+17

Is there any way i can store it as a string? Or cut off the 10 first digits? I don't really need more than the last 5 digits so whatever would work really. I couldnt find any ways to do this after searching for an hour.

Comment: It isn't being *stored* in scientific notation. It is being *displayed* in scientific notation when you call `print()` on it without specifying how you want it to look. You can convert it to a string like this: `"{:15.0f}".format(3.73000005620158e+17)`. You are getting it as a float because Excel is storing it as a float, and Excel promises no more than 15 significant digits of accuracy, so you're about on the limit of what is possible here.

Comment: I see, it prints the ID but 16 off. Is there no other way to read the excel file differently? Any libraries or functions that can read the characters in the cell one by one?

Comment: Your spreadsheet *doesn't have characters* in this value, it has a float, so there is no way to read it character by character. Floats being what they are, any conversion is liable to lose accuracy at the least significant end. No float that has a fractional part ending in 8 in decimal notation can be stored accurately, because it is not a sum of powers of 2. One solution that will work is to change the spreadsheet to store this value as a string (put `'` on the left). If that's not feasible then you could try `openpyxl` instead of `xlrd`. It might not do as much conversion.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for explaining. I will look for a solution in openpyxl.